# Python not found in Alpine image

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux

I'm getting a `python: not found` error in an Alpine container although it shouldn't.

I'm creating an environment from a micromamba image, then copying the environment to an Alpine a clean image and finally adding it to the PATH. The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mambaorg/micromamba:1.5.1 as builder

COPY --chown=$MAMBA_USER:$MAMBA_USER ./env.yaml /tmp/env.yaml
RUN micromamba create -y -n env -f /tmp/env.yaml && \
    micromamba clean --all --yes


FROM alpine:3.18.4 as production

COPY --from=builder /opt/conda/envs/env /opt/conda/envs/env
ENV PATH="/opt/conda/envs/env/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /code
COPY ./app /code/app

WORKDIR /code/app
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

When I run the container and check whether it is using the right Python or not, I'm getting this:

```
$ docker run --rm -it test

/code/app # which python
/opt/conda/envs/env/bin/python
```

So far everything looks fine but when trying to run python I get the following:

```
/code/app # python
/bin/sh: python: not found
```

Anyone knows why it is not being found?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably `/opt/conda/envs/env/bin/python` is a symlink somewhere else, and it's broken. See `ls -la /opt/conda/envs/env/bin/`.

Comment: Is `/opt/conda/envs/env/bin/python` perhaps a symbolic link to a file that no longer exists?

Comment: @AKX It is in fact a symlink: `16:52 python -> python3.11` but it is to the same directory that has the actual file: `16:52 python3.11`

Comment: And what if you try running `python3.11` then?

Comment: Anyway, Alpine uses musl libc, not the default GNU libc that practically every other image uses; you're probably better off with something non-Alpine. Related: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/

Comment: @AKX same error: `/bin/sh: python3.11: not found`

Comment: Yep, my bet is on that "not found" means "can't find the libc this executable is linked against" now.

Comment: @AKX I tried `debian:stable-slim` and it works just as expected. Is there an image similar to alpine that uses GNU libc?

Comment: You may want a Distroless image: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless#what-images-are-available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have a bad time transplanting stuff compiled against GNU libc (most things and images) into an image that uses musl libc (Alpine).

The `not found` (cryptically enough) means GNU libc isn't found.

You should use a libc-based base image; Google's [distroless images](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) have e.g. `gcr.io/distroless/base-debian12` that could maybe work for you if you want a small image – or you can just go with a regular Debian image too.